# Web 8.5 - Experience Manager Boostrap URL pointing to localhost, how to change to actual website url?

Tags: experience-manager, web8.5

I have Web 8.5 setup with the latest CD Environment.  I am using XPM on DWTs and when I publish a page whose template has the "Enable inline editing for Page" TBB on it.  I see the SiteEdit script tag output with the following URL: "http://localhost:80/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js"
however, it is clearly pointing to localhost which will only work on the CM server itself.  How do I change this to point to the actual website URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This URL is derived from your CmEnvironment as it is defined in the Topology Manager Database.  By running the Powershell script "Get-TtmCmEnvironment" you can see the current environment.  By running the script "Set-TtmCmEnvironment" you can update the environment.

Example:

```
PS ExamplePath> Get-TtmCmEnvironment


CoreServiceRootUrl     : net.tcp://localhost:2660
WebsiteRootUrl         : Http://localhost:80
CoreServiceCredentials : "AuthenticationType":"Windows", "UserName":"exampleUser", "Password":"examplePassword"
Id                     : ExampleId
ExtensionProperties    : {}




PS ExamplePath> Set-TtmCmEnvironment -Id ExampleId -CoreServiceRootUrl net.tcp://localhost:2660 -WebsiteRootUrl http://actualpath


CoreServiceRootUrl     : net.tcp://localhost:2660
WebsiteRootUrl         : http://actualpath
CoreServiceCredentials : "AuthenticationType":"Windows", "UserName":"exampleUser", "Password":"examplePassword"
Id                     : ExampleId
ExtensionProperties    : {}
```

Comment: It is recommended to leave the `CoreServiceRootUrl` at the default `net.tcp://localhost:2660` (so only change `WebsiteRootUrl`).

Comment: @RickPannekoek I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Partially :-)  Note the protocol and port.

Comment: Further details on this (e.g. Where the configuration comes from when using legacy publishing) can be found in Bart's answer here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/15100/71