# Usage of the `WebsiteRootUrl` setting in Topology Manager

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager

This question is related to the following two questions:

1. [Web 8.5 - Experience Manager Boostrap URL pointing to localhost, how to change to actual website url?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18959/web-8-5-experience-manager-boostrap-url-pointing-to-localhost-how-to-change-t/) by Nicholas Whetmore
2. [How to enable XPM button on DXA, SDL Web 8](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/how-to-enable-xpm-button-on-dxa-sdl-web-8/) by Hirokazu Shikata

I can see from the answers to those two questions that the `WebsiteRootUrl` setting in Topology Manager is used by both:

1. **Experience Manager** - When using the `Enable inline editing for Page` TBB, and
2. **The `Publish Settings` Page** (in the `_System` Structure Group) - When using DXA.

[image]

My question is whether the `WebsiteRootUrl` setting in Topology Manager is used anywhere other than in these two places in a standard installation (excluding in any customisations, etc.).

For example, if the URL of the Content Manager changed, and we did not update this configuration, what other problems might we see?

Presumably the lookup when adding Topology Mappings, etc. is done using the `CoreServiceRootUrl` setting, so I wouldn't expect that to be impacted?

Comment: Is this Question just out of curiosity or are you experiencing issues that you think may be related to this setting?

Comment: Our CMS URL has changed, but I've not updated this setting yet. Nothing appears to be broken (it's not a DXA site and the website gets the URL for the XPM JavaScript using a different mechanism), but I'm wondering what specifically I should be looking out for that may (now) be broken to feed into my test cases.

Comment: Right. Indeed, you may get quite far with this setting being incorrect whilst nobody notices.

Comment: Excellent. I do plan to update it, but was wondering what it may break (or fix!) before making the change.

Comment: Was wondering the same :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two use cases you mentioned are the only ones that spring to my mind for OOTB functionality. Note that both use cases are about Experience Manager support (the main reason why DXA publishes this setting is to generate XPM markup).

Indeed, all communication between Topology Manager and Content Manager is done using the Core Service and based on the `CmEnvironmnent.CoreServiceRootUrl`.